Does the three-pin diode have a half current?
I need a 30 amp diode for the battery backup. I have used an MBRF30100CT diode. But I don't know the diode current is 30 amps or half of it is 15 amps.

What datasheet do you refer to? (None I could discern in above question post.)

The datasheet clearly says 15 A average forward current PER LEG and 30 A PER DEVICE.  So both diodes have to be in parallel to carry 30 A.  You still have to be sure that you don't exceed the maximum junction temperature.  (Heatsink, cooling, etc.)

Right there in the datasheet:
Average Rectified Forward Current IF (AV): 15 (Per Leg), 30 (Per Device)
